# Business Objects suppress row when column is 0

Tags: business-objects

A program that we uses has an embedded Business Objects reporting program.

A particular report it generates looks like the below:

[image]

I want to not show the roles where the last column equals 0:00.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to edit report in any way? May be you have *.wid file?

If yes, then you can add filter to table or block of data with condition [2-20]<>"0:00" or something like that.